# Inspect UI component tree in windows

Tags: java, c#, windows, user-interface, windows-7-x64

I am task with automating a UI test for an application developed in C#. Target System is Windows 7 and I am basically a Java Developer.

Since I use pattern matching (like sikuli), I would also like to check what the UI component tree would offer me. I therefore look for ways to first manually (tool) and secondly programmatically (library / dll / java.lib) walk the component tree of windows.

For the manual (tool) part all I found was Inspect.exe that comes with the Windows SDK + DotNet. But I do not know if this is available for Windows 7 since I already have DotNet installed and inspect.exe is not available.

For the programmatically part I have not found anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is developed with WinForms, you can use [Hawkeye](https://hawkeye.codeplex.com/) which will allow you to inspect all controls: read and modify their properties.

In WPF, you can use XAML Spy or a free tool such as [Snoop](https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf).